# "<<<<<<" symbol in source code

Tags: python, diff

I'm reading Python code of someone else and see these symbols appear on top of the file:

```
<<<<<< .mine
```

There are also

```
>>>>>>
```

and

```
=======
```

I'm not sure what that is. When compiling, the interpreter throws a syntax error at that line.

Does anyone know the meaning of this line?

Answer (score 8):

Those are markers for conflicts from your source control - they're marking which changes are yours, and which changes are from whatever you tried to merge in.

Comment: so what should I do to make it work? just delete the strange symbols?

Comment: The symbols should usually match up to mark sections of your code - there'll be a `mine` section and a `theirs` section. They're getting marked because your source control isn't able to figure out which to choose - so if you delete the symbols along with one of the sections inside them, you can fix your code (by 'choosing' the section you didn't delete). Here are two tutorials on merging (for subversion and git): http://www.pointbeing.net/weblog/2009/04/command-line-subversion-tutorial-part-2.html, http://blog.springsource.com/2010/12/21/git-and-social-coding-how-to-merge-without-fear/

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by an incomplete SVN merge. SVN attempted to modify the file to show you a diff of the conflict, but someone committed or left the file as-is before the conflict was resolved. You need to resolve this conflict through SVN.

Comment: Not necessarily subversion...it could have been any source control

Answer (score 0):

Those are the result of a conflict while merging two versions.

Answer (score 0):

Those look like notes by a version control system's conflict report. It means when someone committed a file to the VCS, there was a conflict in one of the files and it wasn't fixed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like leftovers from a [diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) went bad.